# How to switch the local version of .net core？

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I downloaded the VS2022 for mac version，It seems to install the .net6 version of the environment for me by default, and I installed a 3.1 version myself. The local environment is as follows:
[image]

How do I switch the default .net6 version to the 3.1 version？

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version ?

Comment: You can try changing the target framework and point it to 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the target framework version from project .csproj file and change the `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` value to your .net version. Alternatively you can introduce a `global.json` to use a exact specified version for the solution/project, just place it in the project directory.

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.1.100",
    "rollForward": "disable"
  }
}
```